# Duplicação de URL de post acrescenta valor numérico

Tags: wordpress, url, post, seo

Eu imaginava que pertencendo a diferentes categorias, estes posts, de nomenclatura de url iguais, seriam tradadas como distintas.

**Categorias:**

- Casa
- Hotel

**Posts:**

- rua a
- rua a

> **URL gerada:**

- www.meu.com.br/casa/rua-a
- www.meu.com.br/hotel/rua-a-2

**Gostaria de saber como resolver isso, pois imagino que isso afeta o >SEO<.**

Qual a solução para definir que **Casa** e **Hotel** *PERTENCEM* a mesma rua para **evitar** que seja acrescentado esse valor **numérico 2**?

Comment: Alguém pode ajudar ??

Answer (score 0):

O wordpress não assume a categoria como uma chave unica de um post (como ele usa o slug [ou o casa-a]). 
Então, mesmo que de categorias diferentes, ele continuará fazendo isso.

Você pode resolver isso criando custom post-types, que ai sim eles se comportam de forma diferentes, da mesma forma que um post e uma página podem ter o mesmo slug.